# Python - Decoding dictionary value List<bytes> to List<String> without "b" notation

Tags: python

Novice Python (3.7) question here - I'm attempting to decode a Python dictionary's keys which are represented as lists of byte objects to a class but am seeing that the byte notation is not being removed as a part of decoding.

Can anyone help me achieve this without just bolting on something like v.replace("b", "")?

**Application.py**

```
from Person import Person
person = {
    'firstName': [b'Foo'],
    'lastName': [b'Bar'],
    'email': [
        b'foo.bar@example.com',
        b'bar.foo@example.com',
    ],
}

p = Person(person)
print(p.firstName)
print(p.lastName)
print(p.email)
```

**Person.py**

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        for key in dictionary:
            value_list = dictionary[key]
            for v in value_list:
                v.decode('utf-8')
            setattr(self, key, dictionary[key])
```

**Running Application.py outputs this**

```
[b'Foo']
[b'Bar']
[b'foo.bar@example.com', b'bar.foo@example.com']
```

**But I require this (without "b'" notation)**

```
['Foo']
['Bar']
['foo.bar@example.com', 'bar.foo@example.com']
```

Comment: @DeepSpace please do not close this question without reading it through - you can see in my question here that I have attempted to use decode as mentioned in the associated answer you linked this to, however it is not working correctly in my case.

Comment: Just do this inside your for loop of your class: `value_list = [v.decode('utf-8') for v in dictionary[key]];setattr(self, key, value_list)` remove everything else. You were using decode, but not using or storing the decoded part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        for key, values in dictionary.items():
          try:
            new_values = []
            for value in values:
              new_values.append(value.decode('utf-8'))
            setattr(self, key, new_values)
          except:
            setattr(self, key, values.decode('utf-8'))



person = {
    'firstName': [b'Foo'],
    'lastName': [b'Bar'],
    'email': [
        b'foo.bar@example.com',
        b'bar.foo@example.com',
    ],
}

p = Person(person)
print(p.firstName)
print(p.lastName)
print(p.email)
```

Output:

```
['Foo']
['Bar']
['foo.bar@example.com', 'bar.foo@example.com']
```

*Note*: your mistake is that you are using the original value ( `dictionary[key]`) in `setattr` not the decoded one (`value.decode('utf-8')`).